# Feature request - assign a tab-index to notification link

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability, stack-exchange-button

I see the search box in the upper-right of every page on every SE site has a `tabindex` of 1. Which is really useful and handy as it is the most used by users.

I suggest, to add a `tabindex` of 2 to the `StackExchange` link in the top-left corner of the window clicking on which pops a Notification box with options `Hot questions`, `all sites`, `inbox` and `notification.`

Screenshot, to be more specific:

[image: TabIndex feature-request]

This would be helpful, and would save a little user key-board homing time.

Comment: I guess it's not yet seen by any mod yet.