# Can I just retag from the edit link?

Tags: support, tags, edits

I wanted to retag [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148730/167534), and clicked the edit link as I would normally do on SO. I got a message saying:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - You have the privilege to retag questions; to suggest an edit please include a change to the title and/or the body as well

So I went back and tried the retag link, and it just worked. Then I tried the edit link again on a different question, adding some random tag and a stupid description, and to my surprise a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7521) was submitted (and rejected – sorry for that, Anna Lear). I tried yet again [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148744/167534), and got the warning message again.

I'm confused, can't I just retag a question from the edit link, without submitting a suggested edit?

Comment: You could've added a better edit message, just in case. :P

Comment: I realize that *now*. I could also have added a better tag, just in case.

Comment: [The retag privilege has been removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#179401), so this issue is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Until you hit 2000 reputation and gain the privilege to [edit questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), the only way you can make an edit is as a suggested edit.

However, the privilege to [retag questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions) is gained at a mere 500 reputation. Thus, for users who have between 500 and 1999 reputation, they'll need to use the "edit tags" link that appears to the right of the tags.

Once you hit 2000 reputation and you have full privileges to edit questions and answers, there's no need for a separate link to edit only tags, and at that point in time, you'll be able to use the edit link under the question to edit tags.

In fact, between 2K and 10K reputation, the only option to edit tags is to actually edit the question. Once you hit 10K, the "edit tags" link comes back.

I suspect that part of the reason for the separation is because the privileges to edit questions and answers and the privilege to edit just tags come at different stages of reputation; thus, it's probably easier to just have the users use the "edit tags" link to edit tags in lieu of modifying the suggested edit logic.  This does seem like a confusing workflow, and it probably could be improved at some point.

Comment: I didn't realize the retag link didn't show between 2K and 10K, that's probably why I got used to using the regular edit link on SO. But I still can't understand how I was able to suggest that edit that only changed the tags. As I explained, it happened once and I'm unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeh, it caught be by surprise too! I was approving tag suggested edits until someone pointed out that those users could just use the retag link...